# Add side effects to scala yield statement

Tags: scala, yield

In the following scala for loop

```
private val tpath = for (csvPath <- CsvPaths
  if new java.io.File(csvPath).exists()
) yield csvPath
```

I would like to add a println side effect - similar to the following:

```
private val tpath = for (csvPath <- CsvPaths
  if new java.io.File(csvPath).exists() {  // Following is illegal syntax
    println(s"Following path exists $csvPath")
  }
) yield csvPath
```

So is there any syntax for adding the side effect to the for/yield loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an _ assignment:

```
for {
  csvPath <- CsvPaths
  if (new java.io.File(csvPath).exists())
  _ = println(s"Following path exists $csvPath")
} yield csvPath
```

Of course for this specific example you could just use a block for the yield:

```
for {
  csvPath <- CsvPaths
  if (new java.io.File(csvPath).exists())
} yield {
  println(s"Following path exists $csvPath")
  csvPath
}
```

but the above technique is useful if you want to put calls in the "middle" of a for/yield chain with more `<-` lines afterwards.

Comment: Not familiar with the _ assignment. Can you explain a little more about how/when it may be used?

Comment: Looks like it means "ignore me" . So yes it seems that syntax were required since an assignment is needed in that location.

Comment: Syntactically `_ <- ...` is similar to `case _ => ...` - you can often times treat the left hand side of the `<-` as a pattern match.

Comment: Yeah, you could equally well write `ignoreMe = println(...)`. The point is to assign the `{}` returned by `println` to *something*, because the syntax only allows assignments here.

Answer (score -1):

```
for {
  csvPath <- CsvPaths
  _ = if(new java.io.File(csvPath).exists()) println(...)
} yield csvPath
```

or

```
for {
  csvPath <- CsvPaths
} yield {
  if(new java.io.File(csvPath).exists()) println(...)
  csvPath
}
```

Comment: It loses the filtering action of the 'if' clause in the original